# How to get all files from SVN any version?

Tags: subversion

For example, my SVN Server have version 3 and version 4.
Two files in version 3: `aaa.txt` and `bbb.txt`

`aaa.txt`'s content is :

```
1234
```

`bbb.txt`'s content is :

```
abcd
```

In version 4, `aaa.txt`'s content is updated:

```
1234def
```

`bbb.txt`'s content unchanged:

```
abcd
```

Now,I want to get files from version 3 and keep `aaa.txt`'s content as `1234` and `bbb.txt`'s content as `abcd`.

The same for version 4, when I get files from version 4, I want to keep `aaa.txt`'s content as `1234def`  and `bbb.txt`'s content as `abcd`.

Comment: I don't understand your question. How is this different from checking out version 3 or checking out version 4?

Comment: @ Gilles - Checking out with version number is a good idea,but what can I do to get files which was changed only? In another words,I just want to get files which was changed with every SVN version rather than all of files.

Comment: I still don't understand. Do you want to do a partial checkout? Do you already have a checkout and what to update? Do you want to get a diff without making a checkout?

Comment: @ Gilles - Yes, I just want to export files which was modified between different version of SVN, for example version 3 and version 4. A good idea what I get:svn diff --summarize -r 3:4 svn://172.20.114.136/MSD6308/Supernova | awk ' { print $2 }'   And this is what I want to do.  Many thanks in the last.